# String Replace based on attribute

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have a file string as below

```
<html>
<head>
    <body>
        <normalstring>
            <ul>            
                <li>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </normalstring
            <teststring name="one" delete="yes">
                <ul>            
                    <li>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </teststring>
            <teststring name="one" delete="yes">
                <ul>            
                    <li>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </teststring>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

I want to find the string node `<teststring>` and take take the entire string from `<teststring> to </teststring>`
After taking the string, i want to find the string has attribute "delete" or not?
If the found string has "delete" i want to replace the entire string with "empty" (i mean i want to delete the found substring and it's content"
If there is no "delete" attribute in the found string, i want to delete the node only `<teststring name="one" delete="yes">` not the inside content.

I want to handle this in string not to convert the string as document. as i am getting some issue after parsing the string to document.

Thanks,
Jey

Comment: And what did you try so far ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should read up on some XML parsing documents. There are several XML parsers, however I usually use the DOM parser. Great documentation can be found at www.w3schools.com 
To reach  node, you have to create a DocumentBuilderFactory, a documentBuilder, and a Document. Next, you have to search the document for the desired node name, like the following example:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder b = f.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = b.parse(File file);
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("teststring");
```

Next, to retrieve a node attribute, you have to create an Element object to store a specific node from the NodeList and use a String to store the value of the attribute. You can create a loop to traverse all the nodes stored and only reach the one you want.

```
Element ele = nodes.item(i);
String s = ele.getAttribute("delete");
```

You can then check if the string stored in `s` matches "yes" with `.equals` command. I leave the last part to you, figure out how to delete the field you desire. Hope this helped :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I have done this using xml parser, but i want to do this in using Regex.